# Package names in eclipse when importing from directory

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am importing several .java files located in different directories ( I just import the whole directory above them ). They use each other in their inner workings and they use the package names to know where each one is located ( for imports ).

Am I supposed to change these package names to the /path/ in the tree view? For example /org/demo/analysis/ to org.demo.analysis.? It doesn't seem to work - am I supposed to set up the package names somewhere in the project settings?

I just want to import the files and have them work. After all they are all out there but Eclipse doesn't seem to find them even if I add them to the build path.

Comment: is your package "/org/demo/analysis" under the src folder?

Comment: It's in a separate folder.

Comment: If you can try, try to place your package structure under src folder of your project in eclipse and than add this src folder under the Build Path configuration. like "your project name/src". See if it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse enforces that the source folder structure follow the package declarations in the classes (`.java` files). So, for example, if a class has a declaration like:

```
package com.myco.stuff;

public class MyThing {
}
```

Then Eclipse requires it to be in a folder structure like this (note the folders corresponding to package segments under the root of the project's source folder):

```
MyProject/
    src/
        com/
            myco/
                stuff/
                    MyThing.java
```

(where `src/` is defined in `MyProject` as a Source Location).

This is not a strict requirement enforced by the JDK compiler `javac`, but it is a widely accepted best practice. Eclipse has chosen to enforce it.